# How to keep changes when switching branches without using `git stash`

Tags: git, git-checkout

I made some changes on branch x but I have *not staged or committed* any new changes, I get:

```
% git checkout other/existing/branch
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        apps/node-be/package.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

for some reason, I was under the impression that if the changes were not staged or commited that they were would be moved over (I swear that happens sometimes), but I guess it clearly would cause conflicts, so a merge would be necessary.

Is there a flag to checkout a branch and if there are no conflicts keep the changes?

```
git checkout --mine other/existing/branch
```

the other way to do this seems to be:

```
git stash
git checkout other/existing/branch
git stash apply
```

so I guess, in a way, I would be looking for a one-line command:

```
git checkout --from-stash other/existing/branch
```

or whatever

Comment: *I swear that happens sometimes* that happens if the file is not tracked

Comment: @Paolo yes that's what I was thinking, so if a file is not tracked it's not in version control. But otherwise, even if changes are not added/committed, then it still will barf when trying to checkout to another branch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may run in conflicts, but you can use the `--merge` option (a.k.a `-m`) to keep your local changes, even if the files were changed between the branches you're switching from/to.

```
git checkout --merge other/existing/branch
```

or the more modern

```
git switch --merge other/existing/branch
```

Comment: thanks, isn't there also an option to dictate which branch supercedes the other, or is that extraneous/orthogonal to this issue?

Comment: `git checkout` has  the options `--ours` and `--theirs` (they are to be used instead of `--merge`). However I do *not* know if that actually works in your use-case and can't test that right now either. That being said: feel free to try if those options do anything for you and post an answer if it solves your problem. Looking at the manpage I guess you'lll probably need `--theirs`, not `--ours`, because from the perspective of the checkout, your commit is on the "other" side - the side getting rebased. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Comment: (Also options like `--ours` and `--theirs` tend to hide potential conflicts and can cause careless people or people in a rush to break code. That's why I am not a big fan of recommending those)